# How create a html tree menu with striped background

Tags: html, css, treeview

I'm trying to create a tree, but am not able to fix the stripes for a specific row. When reducing browser size background stripes not fix for specific `li`.

This is how my html look like

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="node in treeData track by $index" class="overflow-ellipsis" ng-if="node.nodeType">
        <span ng-if="node.nodeType == 'data'" class="ng-scope">

            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" ng-show="(node[childNodeLabel].length || !node.isLeafNode) &amp;&amp; !node.collapsed" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)"></i>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop ng-hide" ng-hide="node[childNodeLabel].length || !node.isLeafNode"></i>
            <i class="node-type JOB" ng-mouseleave="onMouseRemove(node,$event)" ng-mouseover="onMouseOver(node,$event)" ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)"></i>
            <span ng-class="node.selected" ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)" ng-mouseleave="onMouseRemove(node,$event)" ng-mouseover="onMouseOver(node,$event)" class="ng-binding">Job 2</span>

        </span>
        <section class="fokker-tree" style="font-size: 14px;font-size: 14px" ng-hide="node.collapsed" tree-config="treeConfig" tree-data="node[childNodeLabel]">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="node in treeData track by $index" class="overflow-ellipsis" ng-if="node.nodeType">
                    <span ng-if="node.nodeType == 'data'" class="ng-scope">

                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" ng-show="(node[childNodeLabel].length || !node.isLeafNode) &amp;&amp; !node.collapsed" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)"></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop ng-hide" ng-hide="node[childNodeLabel].length || !node.isLeafNode"></i>
                        <i class="node-type JOB" ng-mouseleave="onMouseRemove(node,$event)" ng-mouseover="onMouseOver(node,$event)" ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)"></i>
                        <span ng-class="node.selected" ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)" ng-mouseleave="onMouseRemove(node,$event)" ng-mouseover="onMouseOver(node,$event)" class="ng-binding">Job 2</span>

                    </span>
                    <section class="fokker-tree" style="font-size: 14px;font-size: 14px" ng-hide="node.collapsed" tree-config="treeConfig" tree-data="node[childNodeLabel]">

                    </section>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Code sample https://jsfiddle.net/shibincc/npLjrt66/
Expected result

[image]

Comment: You told us about your goal and your output but didn't show any code. Please post your code. This will help others to answer your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shibincc/npLjrt66/